# Angular5 Nested Array Form Validation FormBuilder

Tags: angular, angular5, formbuilder

I want to create a for validator using FormBuilder for an object that contains an array...and each of those items in that array also contain an array.

The basic view layout is like this

```
Category 1
     Item 1.1
     Item 2.2 
     ...
Category 2 
     Item 2.1
     Item 2.2
....
```

I'm creating the form in the back..first up in the list of Categories:

```
this.complexForm = formBuilder.group({
  'category': formBuilder.array([])
});
```

Category is basically a name (Category 1) and a list of items

```
{name: 'Category1',items:formBuilder.array([])}
```

In the add function i push an item to the category.

```
    category.items.push(this.formBuilder.group({description:'Item 1.1'}));
```

On the view side is where I have my questions. Can someone show me how i would bind the inputs and setup the second ngFor loop so that it binds to the form in the component? I cant seem to decipher how to separate the two lists since they are nested.

```html
<table class="table category-table" *ngFor="let category of complexForm.controls.category.controls;let i=index;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
 <th class="category-header"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="CATEGORY 1" ></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 <tr *ngFor="EACH ITEM IN CATEGORY1 ITEMS list">
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="item.description(ITEM 1.1)"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <button class="btn btn-link" (click)="addCheckListItem()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add check-list item</button>
  </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the validation in your code?

Comment: I havent added it yet, was basically just going to be required on the input fields. I needed the view hooked up so i can start testing it but for the life of me couldn't figure out how.